# Plotting just some data from .dat file (set range)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot 2-columns data from .dat files. In these files, there are 2 columns of ordered numbers (let's say from 0 to 20). And what I want to do is plot/load them for example from 10 to 18 but I also want the graph range (xlim) from 0 to 20.

This is the code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
for f in zip(dataFiles):
    data = np.loadtxt(f)
    plt.plot(data[:,0],data[:,1])
```

I tried `np.arange(10,18)` but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply specify the start and stop indices in your array: `data[10:18,0]`.
You can then use `xlim` to set the limits of the x axis:

```
plt.plot(data[10:18,0])
plt.plot(data[10:18,1])
plt.xlim(left=0,right=20)
```